# What I need to do to learn Quality Assurance?

Tags: quality, qa

I am a Biology student, who has changed my career to IT and have been working in the software field for the past 4 fours under the **QA (auditing processes for ISO9001 purposes)**. Now I'm a Software QA Execute and have decided to increase my knowledge on QA. What are the next steps I can look for?

Are there any **certifications** that I can do under QA, which will be very useful? (I have already done certification on IQA). I have heard about **CSQA** certifications for QA, are there any other certifications apart from these?

Or as always, are there any books for upgrading my knowledge on QA?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by QA? E.g. are you testing software, or are you auditing processes (e.g. for ISO9001 purposes).

Comment: I'm working under auditing processes (i have edited too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are auditing, you need to get ahold of your country's equivalent of the US GAAP (Generally Accepted Accounting Priniciples) and learn it in depth. Even if you are not auditing financial systems, some concepts such as internal controls are most helpful in auditing systems as I find that developers are unaware of these things and leave gaping holes in their software that allow people (especially internal users) to manipulate the data in an unauthorized way. If you are auditing finacial systems GAAP will contain the rules you most need to make sure the system enforces. I believe that the AICPA will also have a lot of information on auditing financial information systems and possibly certifications, at least they had that kind of information back in the 1990s when I worked for an audit agency.

Comment: any kind of books for these certifications?

Answer (score 0):

Do you like breaking things? QA is all about breaking stuff, then telling the guys who can fix it how. Don't know if a certification exists for this, but if you constantly void warranties that is a good start.

Comment: `"QA is all about breaking stuff, then telling the guys who can fix it how"`, that is only exploratory testing. QA is much, much wider. It encompasses various types of functional and non-functional testing.

Comment: Your understanding of "exploratory testing" seems to be somewhat lacking - try Cem Kaner's definition first: http://www.satisfice.com/kaner/?p=42 (he coined the term), and then try reading this: http://www.developsense.com/blog/2008/09/evolving-understanding-about/  There is nothing in the definition of "exploratory testing" that excludes any type of functional or non-functional testing.

Comment: That and you can break stuff in a "so, what happens when you hit this with a hammer" fashion or you can systemically break things but the point is pushing systems to the breaking point.

Comment: @testerab, your understanding of my comment seems somewhat lacking too. I didn't say that exploratory testing includes functional and non-functional testing, I said that QA does.

Comment: @Wyatt Barnett, +1 for a good point, but fully functioning systems that don't function according to spec will fail tests while not "breaking".

Comment: @Stuperuser, the problem is that you're saying "that is only exploratory testing. QA is much, much wider", and then you name things that would be part of an exploratory testing approach. Did you mean to imply ET cannot include non-functional testing? If so - then your understanding is at odds with Cem Kaner's. (I think his definition is canonical, don't you?) If that's not what you meant to convey, what did you mean? What do you think ET is?

Comment: "QA is all about breaking stuff, then telling the guys who can fix it how", that is only exploratory testing. QA is much, much wider. Quality Assurance encompasses various types of functional and non-functional testing.

Comment: @StuperUser, you're basically saying that Cem Kaner is wrong. I think he knows rather a lot more than you do about exploratory testing, testing, and QA. But if you're not interested in that, and it's clear you've not read any of the links, then there really is nothing else that's worth saying.

Comment: Not really. I read the links and I've been trying to clarify my original comment rather than attempt to correct other's definitions.

Answer (score 0):

A programmer friend who writes hardware diagnostics for a living has a framed sign on his wall:

## *KILL!!*

That has to be the mindset of a successful QA guy.

Comment: What does it stand for?

Comment: Breaking stuff.

Comment: @Wyatt - I didn't break it, it was already broken when I got it! ;)

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the **International Software Testing Qualifications Board**'s website: http://istqb.org/

In particular: http://istqb.org/display/ISTQB/Certification

Comment: Why the downvotes?